# Is it possible to mount samba shares with ubuntu touch (bq aquaris 4.5)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samba, file-sharing

Is it possible to mount cifs shares on the ubuntu phone? (terminal suggestions are acceptable).

If it is not possible, is it possible to browse such shares?

I tried to install cifs-tools over apt-get, however apt-get does not seem to be the way to install something on the phone.

Comment: Does this mean that Ubuntu Phone will never be able to copy from ant to drive shares?
Is this an inteded stonewalling or a secondary effect due to a critical (security) flaw of network shares?
Is Canonical trying to appease OEMs and Operators, or trying to force users to use Cloud Drives?

Comment: Does this mean that Ubuntu Phone will never be able to copy from and to drive shares? As I understood the answer, no. It means that you will never be able to mount the shares (as I am also not able on my android phone). But you will be able to copy to and from, provided some clever guy builds an application in user space (as e.g Ghost Commander can do on the same android device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to mount these shares, no. The *cifs* kernel support is not build into the kernel used for the phone images.

It would be possible to build an app to browse such shares using the CIFS protocol entirely in user space, but it would not be able to maintain persistent mounts or such, due to the application life cycle.